# Paste operation to be disabled in google sheet cell

Tags: google-sheets-formula

**I want to restrict copy and paste operation in the cell of google sheet ex- if i apply data validation in cell then user should not be able to paste any data in that cell**

I tried data validation and appscript along with conditional formatting but not able to eliminate the problem

Comment: did you try: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEggZ.png ?

Comment: Thanks but i want to restrict user from pasting the value here but he should manually hard code the value according to the data validation